# Is there a way of grouping a bunch of related question you want to ask so that answerers can see what you are doing?

Tags: discussion, questions, asking-questions

I’m working in Objective-C, SKSpriteKit and am trying to create a class which will work in both OS X and iOS for flexibility.

I have come across various issues/questions which I want to post onto StackExchange. However, as not all of these issues are absolutely directly related to each other (although they are linked in various ways), so I have placed them across several threads.

Being only able to post a question once every 90 minutes, the posting would be quite sparse, and by the time I’ve posted the next question, the previous questions would probably have already been answered, or disappeared from the front pages.

Is there a way to group these questions together without putting them altogether in one thread? It would be best if the same people answered my group of questions rather than different people for each question — and it would be easier to understand what I am trying to do for the answerers.

If there is no option like this, could I suggest one?

EDIT: At request, here are the questions I wanted to group, as an example:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33342865/have-i-created-the-mutabledeepcopying-protocol-properly

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33352330/objective-c-efficiency-or-archiving-and-then-unarchiving-for-deep-copying-compa

Comment: You can provide a link to the previous questions, but I'd advise against it. **Good questions should be able to stand on their own.** Most people don't generally come looking for a lump of answers, they hit the site from google, looking for the answer to one specific issue. If they have to look at a whole series of different pages for context, the value of the site as a repository of questions and answers is diminished.

Comment: But at the same time, don't overdo it. A question that asks 30 sub-questions isn't useful to anyone but you, and the statistically unlikely person that has the same list of 30 questions.

Comment: But surely if the sub-questions (maybe 5, rather than 30) are very closely related to each other as their answers link together, then they can provide helpful insight for people who are looking at one of the specific questions

Comment: Absolutely, hence the 'don't overdo it'. As long as the question can stand on its own, and is likely to be useful to other people having similar issues with any of the components of the question, (and the question is not too broad) then go for it. If the parts of the question are only related because of the project you're working on, or if the people answering one part of a question are unlikely to be able to resolve all parts of the question with, lets say 500-1000 words of explanation, then you're probably better off breaking it up.

Comment: (continued) Keep in mind that unless others comment, or upvote one of my comments that all of this is just my take on it, and not really the consensus opinion.

Comment: Could you provide a more concrete example - what *are* the questions you're thinking of asking?

Comment: I can provide the links, once I have managed to post them all... with the 90 min slots... that'll probably be by tomorrow since I'm not always online. For now, I'll edit my question to give an idea of what I wanted to ask.

Comment: Your questions are far too broad.  [In one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33342865/have-i-created-the-mutabledeepcopying-protocol-properly), you brought up 8 different questions.  [In the other](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33352330/objective-c-efficiency-or-archiving-and-then-unarchiving-for-deep-copying-compa), you asked 4 different questions.  You should focus on a specific issue that you're having, instead of asking "What's best..." (which is opinion-based).

Comment: But all of those questions I ask are the specific issues I am facing.

Comment: You shouldn't try to ask about all those issues in a single question.  "How do I do this?"  "Is this correct?"  "What's the purpose of this?"  "Is this efficient?" "Do I need this?"  **Pick a specific minimal issue that isn't too broad or opinion-based** instead of hoping someone will write up a long, involved answer to every single question you managed to pose about deep copying.

Comment: "It would be best if the same people answered my group of questions rather than different people for each question" This is not really supported behavior on SO. A interested person who happens to view your questions -- or in more esoteric cases, the only expert who hangs around here -- may answer more than one if they are so inclined, but expecting the same person to guide you through your whole project is not realistic.

Comment: This is an interesting Meta idea, but the links that you've provided don't seem to me to be closely-related enough to warrant a "grouping". They stand as their own posts well enough (albeit -- as others have said here -- being too broad).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> If there is no option like this ...

No there isn't. Stack Overflow questions should be independent from other questions as much as possible. You may add a link to a previous question if you think it might clarify the current question, but it shouldn't be *necessary* to read through this previous question *and* answers.

Most of us answer questions pretty randomly. For you the project you work on is an ongoing process, but it's highly unlikely that other users follow you in this process. If someone answered your question, he'll probably be gone, or be answering some other question, if you are ready for a new one.

**Any question you ask, for most people is very likely to be the first question they read from you.**

So you increase your chances of getting meaningful answers if they understand your questions on themselves.

> ... could I suggest one?

You can always suggest new features. I don't think it's worth the effort though. As I explained, clustered questions just doesn't fit the Stack Overflow format.

Comment: Thank you - I'll bear that in mind. Perhaps Stack Overflow isn't the best place to ask "clustered questions" like that then.