# Proposal to group your related questions together in a series

Tags: discussion, feature-request, questions

I think it would be useful if we could group questions together in (a) series.

For example, the Documentation Beta updates are a series of questions, but they aren't grouped as such:

- [Documentation Update, September 29th](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/335529/documentation-update-september-29th?cb=1)
- [Documentation Update, September 12th](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334404/documentation-update-september-12th)
- [Documentation Update, August 29th](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333420/documentation-update-august-29th)
- [Documentation Update, August 4th](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/331663/documentation-update-august-4th)
- [Documentation Update, July 25th](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/329557/documentation-update-july-25th)

There is no [documentation-updates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/documentation-updates) tag, so the only way to link these questions together is in the question body:

> This is the fifth post in our series of regular (roughly <s>fortnightly</s> weekly) updates on the Documentation Beta. See also the [previous post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334404/documentation-update-september-12th) in the series.

If these questions were grouped together in a series, it would look something like this:

[image]

The ability to group questions in (a) series wouldn't only be used for this. It would also be useful to link [follow-up questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266767/what-is-the-the-best-way-to-ask-follow-up-questions) together in a series.

Comment: Does a series of questions happen often enough? And more importantly, does it ever happen outside of Meta? Also, what's stopping anyone for just creating the [documentation-updates] tag?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This doesn't really come up often enough on Meta that it would be useful.

On the main site, I think it would actually be harmful by encouraging -- however subtly or implicitly -- the idea that answerers on Stack Overflow are here to [personally help you develop a project from start to finish](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/308796/is-there-a-way-of-grouping-a-bunch-of-related-question-you-want-to-ask-so-that-a). This, fortunately, isn't too common either, but there's no reason to make it more so.